# I am using Selenuim on python. I need to update value for two Webelement but am able to only update for one

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the page source code snippet.

```html
    <tr>
     <th>Model Name<span class="c-c60000 txtNormal">*</span></th>
        <td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td><input tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" value="" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="inputText" name="modelName" id="modelName" style="width:150px;" style = "ime-mode:disabled"/>&nbsp;</td><td><table class="btnTypeA"><tr><td>
         <a href="javascript:popUpModelSearch();">Search</a>
         </td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td>
      <th>Customer Code<span class="c-c60000 txtNormal">*</span></th>
        <td><input readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="" class="inputText" name="cc" id="cc" style="width:150px;" style = "ime-mode:disabled"/></td>
       </tr>
 <tr>
     <th>Model Alias</th>
        <td><input readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="" class="inputText" name="modelAlias" id="modelAlias" style="width:150px;" style = "ime-mode:disabled"/></td>
        <th>Scenario Type</th>
        <td>
 <select style="width:155px;" name="testOrUse" id="testOrUse" onchange="javascript:loadSubField('');">
        <!-- Admin, Lead Model Developer -->
<option value="T">Testing Scenario</option> 
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

**My code is**

```
element4 = browser.find_element_by_id("modelAlias")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'GT-I9192';", element4)

element2 = browser.find_element_by_id("modelName")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'GT-I9192';", element2)
```

First 2 lines seem to work and value gets updated for "modelAlias"
but last two lines are not working correctly.
Also my code is not throwing any error which is making things difficult.
I think span here is the reason of different behavior.

Comment: Could you try turning things around? As in, try to change value of element2 first and then element4? And see if same thing happens?

Comment: Why do you use `execute_script()` to set values to text input fields? Why not to use `send_keys()`?

Comment: Probably because its a readonly input and you need to change the value through the executor

Comment: @Anand I tried changing element2 first and got the same result.

Comment: So still only element 4 value gets changed?

Comment: @Anand , if it's readonly input then user should not change its value

Comment: @Anand yep only element4 value changed. Both are readonly but only one is working. Need to change value for a project automation.

Comment: Which browser is you used, it is working fine in the Firefox, ut in chrome it is having issue?

Comment: @iamsankalp89 i tried in IE and chrome. same issue on both

Comment: Ok I will try and let u know the solution

Comment: try my answer, by convert it into python

Answer (score 0):

Try this I dont know python too much but you to remove the attribute as it is disabled and then try to pass values, this is javacode. Try to convert it into Python

```
JavascriptExecutor jse =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled','disabled')", element4);
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'GT-I9192';", element4);
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled','disabled')", element5);
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'GT-I9192';", element5);
```